# iOS GridView with Sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, gridview

I am trying to implement my own gridview similar to KKGridView.

My gridview has extra complexity because it needs to support multiple sections with a varying amount of items / cells in each section. (See below)

[image]

It also needs to be able to handle moving one cell from section 1 to section 0 and section 0 to section 1.

I have written the UIView to display the grid but it does not support moving cells from one section to another. The question is does anybody have a gridview that supports this functionality or can advise me of the best way forward as this gridview needs to be supported in iOS 5 & iOS 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try using a combination of `UICollectionView`, with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` along with `PSTCollectionView` for iOS5 compatibility.

- Take a look at the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` docs, I think you'll find everything you need to build a per-section custom layout as you need.
- `PSTCollectionView` is a "open Source, 100% API compatible replacement of UICollectionView for iOS4.3+". Further, you can use `UICollectionView` on iOS6 and only fall back to `PSTCollectionView` on iOS5 devices. Take a look at the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

I'm using this approach in one of the apps I'm working on, and it is really simple to implement.

EDIT: The steps you'd take to make what you want would be roughly as following:

- You need to download at include the `PSTCollectionView` in your project. For that follow the steps on the GitHub page.
- In your `.h` file, import `PSTCollectionView.h` and add the following two protocols: `<PSUICollectionViewDataSource, PSUICollectionViewDelegate>`. Note that with this you'll use Apple's `UICollectionView` in iOS6 and `PSTCollectionView` in iOS5. Here you should also add a property for your collection view: `@property (nonatomic, strong) PSUICollectionView *collectionView;`
- In the `viewDidLoad:` method, you need to have something like this:

Code:

```
PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(91, 119)];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0];
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

- And you'd need to implement the following methods to your liking:

Methods:

```
numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:
collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:
collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Important: Don't forget to prefix every mention of `UICollectionView` classes with `PS`. For example `PSUICollectionView` or `PSUICollectionViewLayout`.

EDIT 2: For a general understanding of `UICollectionView` refer to [this excellent tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12).

Comment: THanks just taking a gander at this now

Comment: No problem. If you have any additional questions, I'll be happy to expand my answer.

Comment: Can you let me know which implementation you think will support what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can use you custom cells to achieve this functionality. One Cell with 10 subViews and 2nd with 6 subView. It will work for you.

you can get the view in the cell by tags i.e 1-6 and 1-10

Try this

Comment: Cannot use this as per my question I need to support iOS 5

Comment: That would work normally but I think that this adds a rigidity to what I am trying to achieve the purpose is to functionally allow the movement of one cell to another section and have the cells in the destination update their positions to reflect the cell moving into the section